ClassPathXmlApplicationContext error in IntelliJ
I have created Spring Initializr project and am having a problem instantiating a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:

I can't understand the core problem, so I am using IntelliJ to get a better understanding.
Please help me solve this problem.
I have also checked external Maven dependencies:


It looks like you have the wrong import for ApplicationContext. Try replacing the org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext import with org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
